# keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Failed to establish chain from reply (certificate)

Tags: java, certificate, rsa, keytool, jks

[image]

keytool -genkey -alias ima -keyalg RSA -keysiz
e 2048 -validity 730 -keystore fake_keystore_name.jks -storetype JKS -storepass fake_keystore_password -keypass fake_keystore_password -dname "CN=0025598, OU=bolbol.az, O=bolbol.az, L=Baku, ST=Baku, C=AZ"

[image]

keytool -certreq -alias ima -file fake_cert_
req.csr -keystore fake_keystore_name.jks -storepass fake_keystore_password```

[image]

Sending and then receiving certificates...

[image]

Folder looks like the above attachment.

[image]

keytool -import -noprompt -alias ima -file certificate.0025598.der -keystore fake_keystore_name.jks -storepass fake_keystore_password

Error:
`keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Failed to establish chain from reply`

Why? How to solve?
I noticed if in the last command I type not the actual .jks filename but something else (like random_keystore_name.jks) it works and gives me "Certificate was added successfully". Why? It is not how it should work. + when I retype the last command with new random filename it gives me `keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Certificate not imported, alias <ima> already exists`. Please help I am stuck!

Comment: no one got an answer? :(